# how to create voice navigation in iOS with google maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, dictionary, map-directions

I have implemented Google maps SDK in iOS, In this I'm showing route to the user from his current location to some other location. Everything is fine upto this, but my requirement is I need to navigate user with voice navigation and directions.Is it possible to implement voice navigation in iOS with google maps?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you have done so far. Do you mean you are writing an app for iOS, in which you have embedded a Google maps interface, and you want to let the user use voice navigation? I have 0 experience with iOS, so with that in mind, i think this is something you should try and interface with the official Google maps app through an api (if available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to implement a real-time navigation? If so, I'm afraid this is prohibited in Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. Have a look at section 10.4 c (iii) of ToS:

> **No navigation.** You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#section_10_4

The only option here is to open a native Google Maps app in navigation mode. You can achieve this using the Google Maps URLs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

There is a directions mode with navigation option in this API.